# how can i make the whole TD area become clickable?

Tags: html, css

I am a new css/html learner 
and I am currently building a website.
I have hover working, but I can't make it become clickable. 
I wanted the whole TD area become clickable not just only the text link become clickable.

Could anyone give me a hand and help me figure it out?

here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ateng/Hja5u/)

Comment: by wrapping it with a tag like this : `<a href = "<some link>"><td>your td code goes here</td></a>`

Comment: height: 100; should be height: 100%;

Comment: @DhruvenkumarShah That's very very bad practice.

Answer (score 5):

```
a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this rule to your CSS

```
td.blue span, td.blue span a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hja5u/4/)

Just a sidenote - you don't need to wrap your links in `<span>`-s